# How to sum object values based on another object key JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects below:

```
    data =  [
    {
        "slno": "1",
        "POno": "P00527",
        "date_of_purchase": "10-03-2022",
        "amountpaid": "0.00",
    },
    {
        "slno": "2",
        "POno": "P00527",
        "date_of_purchase": "10-03-2022",
        "amountpaid": "0.00",
    },
    {
        "slno": "3",
        "POno": "P00527",
        "date_of_purchase": "10-03-2022",
        "amountpaid": "100.00",
    },
    {
        "slno": "4",
        "POno": "P00528",
        "date_of_purchase": "14-03-2022",
        "amountpaid": "200.00",
    },
    {
        "slno": "5",
        "POno": "P00528",
        "date_of_purchase": "14-03-2022",
        "amountpaid": "100.00",
    }
]
```

I want to sum the `amountpaid` if 'POno' is more than one time.

I tried the following code but that did not work:

```
var new_result = [];

for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    let temp = {};
    console.log("inside");
    for(let j=0; j<new_result.length; j++ ){
        if (new_result[j]['POno'] == data[i]['POno']){
            let amount_sum = Number(new_result[j]['amountpaid']) + Number(data[i]['amountpaid']);
            temp['slno'] = new_result[j]['slno'];
            temp['POno'] = POno;
            temp['date_of_purchase'] = date_of_purchase;               
            temp['amountpaid'] = amount_sum;            
            new_result.push(temp);
            
        }
        else{
            temp['slno'] = i+1;
            temp['POno'] = data[i]['POno'];
            temp['date_of_purchase'] =data[i]['date_of_purchase'];
            temp['amountpaid'] = data[i]['amountpaid'];
            new_result.push(temp);
            
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any another way to make this code short and efficient...?

I am bad at javascript, just got some work apart from Python work.

Update:
the end result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "slno":"1",
        "POno":"P00527",
        "date_of_purchase":"10-03-2022",
        "amountpaid":"100.00",
    },
    {
        "slno":"2",
        "POno":"P00528",
        "date_of_purchase":"14-03-2022",
        "amountpaid":"300.00",
    }

]
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of your desired output?

Comment: Check the updated question